# Python Pandas read_csv(): Incorectly loaded csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

according to the Pandas documentation, pandas.read_csv (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) should support detection of bad lines though error_bad_lines and warn_bad_lines set to True.

So I have created a csv with bad format called test.csv:

```
aaa,bbb,ccc
ssdf,sdtf,aesrt,,,,
eart,erate
aert,aert,aert
```

and run read_csv:

```
>>> pd.read_csv('test.csv', error_bad_lines = True )
                      aaa  bbb  ccc
ssdf sdtf  aesrt NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
eart erate NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

As I understand the documentation, this should raise an Error, except it doesn't. Instead bad csv is loaded. Pandas seems to ignore all of error_bad_lines / warn_bad_lines.

Is my understanding of the documentation wrong, or is it really a bug in Pandas? Does anyone know of elegant work-around how to load only correct csv?

I'm working with Python 3.6.8, Pandas 0.25.0 and Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some tests and found that the second line will determine the number of columns to be expected in the rest of the file.

for example, the second line (ssdf,sdtf,aesrt,,,,) has 7 columns. So if all the following rows have less than 7 columns, then no errors!

If you modify one row to be 7 or more, then it will crash. The default value for error_bad_lines is true, so you don't need to specify it explicitly.

Example without an error :

data.csv :

```
0,jjjjjj
1,er,ate,, # 5 columns
2,bb,b
3,sdtf,aesrt,ll,sdfd # 5 columns, so no errors appear.
4,erate,
5,aert,aert


df1 = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df1
```

Result : No error

```
0   jjjjjj
1   er  ate NaN NaN
2   bb  b   NaN NaN
3   sdtf    aesrt   ll  sdfd
4   erate   NaN NaN NaN
5   aert    aert    NaN NaN
```

Example with an error :

data.csv :

```
0,jjjjjj
1,er,ate,, # 5 columns
2,bb,b
3,sdtf,aesrt,ll,sdfd,sdf,sdf,sdf,sdf, # more than 5 columns
4,erate,
5,aert,aert



df1 = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df1
```

Result : error !!

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 4, saw 10
```

Comment: Indeed your are right, I really did not expected number of columns to be set by the second row, not the header (or first line in general). Also as I understand it now, this check doesn't apply when having less columns than in the second row?

Comment: @Michal, Yes, the error only occurred when the number of columns is more than the second line. I didn't find any documentation yet talking about that.